# answer's "share" link goes to a different answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro

When I go to the question [Explaining floating point precision to customers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76804/explaining-floating-point-precision-to-customers) and get a "share" link for Scott Whitlock's answer:

[image]

The [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/768) sends my browser to a different answer on the question [What should you test with unit tests?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/750/what-should-you-test-with-unit-tests)

[image]

Comment: The first link goes to the "wrong" answer, not the question itself.

Comment: @HunterStevens I've fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, that PHP answer is not listed on the "wrong" question you linked...

Comment: @HunterStevens Thanks.  Fixed.  I think the link hasn't always been sending me to the same wrong answer, which made this a confusing question to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce this.

The share link I get for Scott's answer is `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/76884/4`, which consistently goes to Scott's answer. However, the second answer is `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/768/4`. They are close, except the second URL is missing two digits.

Note that `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/768`, which is only the text visible in your share dialog box, goes to the same answer as `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/768/4`.

The last part, `/4`, is my user ID used to track links that I've shared, to grant credit to badges. The last part will change for each person, which is why it isn't required for the link to work.

Are you sure that you are copying the entire link properly and not truncating it?

Comment: Yep, it was an embarassing ID10T error.  Thanks, Thomas.